# Is it possible to develop a recursive word wrap algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, word-wrap, memoization

I want to develop a recursive word wrap algorithm that takes a specified string and wrap length (the maximum number of characters on one line) to return a wrapped output at the input length. I don't want it to break apart words. So for example, `This is the first paragraph that you need to input` with length 20 returns as:

```
This is the first
paragraph that you
need to input
```

I already have a dynamic programming (bottom-up) solution implemented, but I was wondering if it's possible to write an algorithm to do this using just recursion (top-down) instead? I'd also like to memoize it if I can. Please don't give me any runnable code... I"m just wondering about ideas/pseudocode.

Comment: Recursive algorithms with memoization _is_ (90% of the time) dynamic programming.

Comment: Two things: (1) What are your wrapping requirements exactly?  The most basic wrapping algorithm doesn't require any recursion or DP at all -- just keep adding words to the current line, and as soon as you go past the line length, go back one step.  (2) It's funny to be going from (presumably bottom-up) DP to recursion -- a recursion is how you get the DP in the first place!

Comment: Also, what the other comment said, this is solved by a really simple greedy algorithm, no need for dynamic programming here.

Comment: @j_random_hacker There should still be an if-statement in there to check that the word read is not itself greater than the line length, otherwise you'll never get to writing a line, and you'll just write an infinite number of newline characters.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I guess more specifically I'm wondering if there's a top-down approach instead of the bottom-up one I implemented, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You basically just described my requirements right there. Yeah, I know it's a weird train of thought... I tend to over-complicate things!

Comment: @user3681725: No problem, but please *edit your question* to put that info there!

Comment: "Max number of chars on one line" makes me seem that you want a greedy algorithm. You can directly solve this using a loop without any recursion and implementating DP here doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 2):

Something like the pseudocode below should work. (I'm sure we'll get comments if I made a mistake!)

```
function Wrap(the_text,line_len)

if length(the_text) > line_len then
    text_bit = the first few words of the_text, keeping their length shorter than line_len
    remove text_bit from the beginning of the_text
    return text_bit + linefeed + Wrap(the_text, line_len)
else
    return the_text
end if

end function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.Math;

public int RCS(int[] l , int n , int m , int index) {

    // first base condition - if index gets beyond the array 'l' , then return 0;
    if (index > n - 1) return 0;

    // second base condition - if index is the last word i.e there is only one word left in the
    // array to be inserted in the line then return the cost if added in that line.
    if (index == n - 1) return (m - l[n - 1]) * (m - l[n - 1]) * (m - l[n - 1]);

    // make a global cost variable to be returned
    int cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    // Here , we try to select words from the array and apply RCS on the rest of the array.
    // From index to last element , we iteratvely select first , or first two and so on.
    for (int i = index ; i < n ; i++) {
        int current_space_sum = 0 ;
        // we add the length of the selected word. We have selected words in array from index to i.
        for (int k = index ; k <= i ; k++) {
            current_space_sum = current_space_sum + l[k] ;
        }
        // Adding the space between the words choses. If 2 words are chosen , there is one space and so on
        current_space_sum = current_space_sum + i - index;
        // If the length of the chosen words is greater than the line can accept , no need of looking beyond.
        if (current_space_sum > m) break;
        // Iteratively find the minimum cost
        cost =  Math.min(cost , (m - current_space_sum) * (m - current_space_sum) * (m - current_space_sum) + RCS(l , n , m , i + 1));
    }
    return cost;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    WordWrap w = new WordWrap();
    int[] l = {3, 2 , 2 , 5};
    int n = l.length;
    int m = 6;
    int result = w.RCS(l , n , m , 0);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: This works only problem is that there could be overflow when 
subproblem RCS(l , n , m , i + 1) returns cost INT_MAX and we try to add that with the current cost . 

Therefore, I propose the modify the code slightly, change the if condition otherway  around.

Comment: If we observe carefully a pattern emerge that is like matrix chain multiplication problem. We are partitioning string according to the given constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you to get the optimal cost for that problem.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// method to get the optimal cost
int findOptimalCost(int *arr, int s, int e,int lineLength,map<pair<int,int>,int>dp) {

if(s>=e)    // return 0 for the last line because we are not calculating the last line space
    return 0;

if(dp.find({s,e}) != dp.end()) {  // return cost if we already calculate
    return dp[{s,e}];
}

int minCost = INT_MAX;
for(int i=s;i<=e;i++) {
    int sum = 0,space=i-s;
    for(int j =s; j<=i; j++) 
        sum += arr[j];  // add the word length 
    sum += space;  // add the space for words (if 2 word then we will count 1 space ) 
    int cost;
    if(sum<=lineLength) 
        cost = (lineLength-sum)*(lineLength-sum) + findOptimalCost(arr,s+1+space,e,lineLength,dp);  // calculate the cost for perticular line and call for rest line
        if(minCost > cost) {
            minCost = cost; // update the minCost variable if the latest cost is less then the previous calculated cost
        }
    }
return dp[{s,e}] = minCost; // store the minimum cost for particular line and return
}

int main()
{
//code
    int len = 4; // total word in the list
    int arr[] = {3,2,2,5};  // let us assume the length of word
    
    int lineLength = 6; // size of max line length
    
    
    map<pair<int,int>,int> dp;
    cout<<findOptimalCost(arr,0,len-1,lineLength,dp)<<endl;
    
return 0;
}
```